# memcache php storage data

Tags: php, caching

when i use *memcache class* and i try store something to cache, like

```
$cache = new \Memcache;
$cache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die('Could not connect to memcache serwer');
$system = $cache->get('system.class');
if (!$system) {

        $object = new system\core\System('system/core/config/configuration.ini');
        $cache->set('system.class', $object, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 10);
        $system = $cache->get('system.class');

}
$system->start();
```

i stored this data to server cache or to client cache?

Comment: The server cache. Memcache works on server side.

Comment: is possible to sotre data on client side? or do that only browser??

Comment: It is possible. One keyword is "HTML 5 local storage", e.g. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html